# Hover issue with mobile and Tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing a mobile and tablet issue for my hover menu. I need to click twice just to open the drop-down, and I don't really know how to just fix on mobile and tablet sizes.
Here is my code for hover effect:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
}, function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
$(".dropdown-2").hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
}, function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

I want the menu only with one click to open certain drop-down, not with 2 clicks :/ . Please note I'm a beginner on JavaScript and jQuery, so a little explanation would be also great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to the script to only trigger the hover function based on the window/screen size:

```
if($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
    $(".dropdown-2").hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

} else {
    $(".dropdown").click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
    $(".dropdown-2").click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

}
```

A check is made to see if the screen size is great that 1024 pixels (Change this to whatever suites you).

If yes, it will run the dropdown with hover functionality. No (mobile), and it will run the dropdown with click functionality.

**Note**:
If testing responsive functionality on a larger screen , you will need to run a 'resize' function which will check if the screen size has changed since then. So it would be better to wrap the entire code in a function to call again:

```
function hoverOrClick() {
if($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
    $(".dropdown-2").hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

} else {
    $(".dropdown").click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
    $(".dropdown-2").click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideDown("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu-2', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu-2').stop(true, true).slideUp("800");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

}
}
hoverOrClick(); // Runs code the first time

$(window).resize(function(){
 hoverOrClick(); // Runs code again to see if screen size has changed
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but detecting if the device is touch-enabled would be a much better option.

Comment: @jcaron Upvoted. However he'd need to be caution of the new touch enabled desktop computers. I'm not sure if having both mouse click and touch functionality, the device will default to the hover state version under this condition.

Comment: @jcaron There would probably need to be a combination of the 2 e.g. if touch and screen is less that common mobile sizes.